# optimize linq query with multiple include statements

Tags: performance, linq, query-optimization

The linq query takes around 20 seconds for executing on some of the data . When converted the linq to sql there are 3 nested joins that might be taking more time for execution . Can we optimize the below query .

```
var query = (from s in this.Items 
             where demoIds.Contains(s.Id)      
             select)
             .Include("demo1")
             .Include("demo2")
             .Include("demo3")
             .Include("demo4");

return query;
```

The expectation is to execute the query in 3-4 seconds which is now taking  around 20 secs for 100 demoIds .

Comment: How are you constructing `demoIds`? is it static? or you're getting it from your database by executing some query?

Comment: demoIds is list of integer values and it is not static , the value comes from the UI from the form selection from the list of id that I have selected on the UI to perform any operation .

Comment: I had such a problem once, and could not find a solution except for looping through (in your case `demoIds`), get results for each `demoId` and `Union` them all. I hope you get a better solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as your code is concerned it looks like it's the best way to get what you want (Assuming `Include`ing `"demo3"` twice is a typo for this example.).

However, the database you use will have a way to optimize your queries or rather the underlying data structure. Use whatever tool your database provider has to get an execution plan of the query and see where it spends so much time. You might be missing an index or two.

Comment: yes ,  including demo3  is a typo . I will analyse the underlying data structures and the execution plan of the query .
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I advice lazy loading or join query.

Probably SQL output is this query;

```
(SELECT .. FROM table1 WHERE ID in (...)) AS T1
   (INNER, FULL) JOIN (SELECT .. FROM table2) AS T2 ON T1.PK = T2.FOREIGNKEY
   (INNER, FULL) JOIN (SELECT .. FROM table3) AS T3 ON T1.PK = T3.FOREIGNKEY
   (INNER, FULL) JOIN (SELECT .. FROM table4) AS T4 ON T1.PK = T4.FOREIGNKEY
```

But if you can use lazy loading, no need use the Include() func. And lazy loading will solve your problem.

Other else, you can write with join query,

```
var query = from i in this.Items.Where(w=>demoIds.Contains(w.Id))
            join d1 in demo1 on i.Id equals d1.FK
            join d2 in demo2 on i.Id equals d2.FK
            join d3 in demo3 on i.Id equals d3.FK
            select new ... { };
```

This two solutions solve your all problems.
If it continues your problem, I strongly recommended store procedure.

Comment: The sql output is pretty similar to this ,when I checked out the execution plan it has three nested loops and the cost of the operation is 25% to 21% in each of the loops . I will try out your suggestions . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar issue with a query that had 15+ "Include" statements and generated a 2M+ rows result in 7 minutes.

The solution that worked for me was:

1. Disabled lazy loading
2. Disabled auto detect changes
3. Split the big query in small chunks

A sample can be found below:

```
public IQueryable<CustomObject> PerformQuery(int id) 
{
 ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
 ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

 IQueryable<CustomObject> customObjectQueryable = ctx.CustomObjects.Where(x => x.Id == id);

 var selectQuery = customObjectQueryable.Select(x => x.YourObject)
                                                  .Include(c => c.YourFirstCollection)
                                                  .Include(c => c.YourFirstCollection.OtherCollection)
                                                  .Include(c => c.YourSecondCollection);

 var otherObjects = customObjectQueryable.SelectMany(x => x.OtherObjects);

 selectQuery.FirstOrDefault();
 otherObjects.ToList();

 return customObjectQueryable;
 }
```

IQueryable is needed in order to do all the filtering at the server side. IEnumerable would perform the filtering in memory and this is a very time consuming process. Entity Framework will fix up any associations in memory.